# how to detect back button of android in framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

I am recently builing an app using framework7. My app consists of a  html file which has all the views in it. To navigate between the views, a back button is present at the bottom of page.

for back button i am using code

```
var myView = app.view.current;

myView.router.back();
```

If i presses the back button on the android device, the app closes

How can I use the back button of android phone to get to the main page.

> I have use **pushState:true** but it doesnt work for me.

below is my app.js file

```
    // Dom7
    var $ = Dom7;

    // Theme
    var theme = 'auto';
    if (document.location.search.indexOf('theme=') >= 0) {
    theme = document.location.search.split('theme=')[1].split('&')[0];
    }

    // Init App
    var app = new Framework7({
    id: 'io.framework7.testapp',
    root: '#app',
    theme: theme,
    on:{
    pageInit : function(page){
       console.log("page init function called aakash");
       document.addEventListener("backbutton", app.methods.onBackKeyDown, 
    false);
    }
     },
    pushState:true,
    data: function () {
    return {
      user: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      },
    };
    },
   methods: {
     helloWorld: function () {
      console.log('dfvdfv')
      app.dialog.alert('Hello World!');
     },
     onDeviceReady: function() {


     },

    onBackKeyDown: function() {

       console.log("back button pressed");


      }
   },
    routes: routes,
    vi: {
      placementId: 'pltd4o7ibb9rc653x14',
     },

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,  I got a solution!! This worked for me

```
var app = new Framework7({
  initOnDeviceReady:true,
  view:{
     pushState:true,

    } 
});
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks for sharing. Only issue is that if I am on the homepage and press Android back button, sometimes it gives me a "page not found" page.

Comment: doesnt work for me in android 10 , framework7 v6

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this problem and solved it with a method

(If you are using webview)

Android Java native code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:goBack();", null);
    }
    return true;
}
```

javascript in your framework app js

```
function goBack() {
   myView.router.back();
}
```

Or

```
function goBack() {
$('.back').trigger('click')
}
```

Try this in jquery function

Comment: Add to main activity

Comment: So it's the **platform/android/app/src/main/java/com/appName/app/MainActivity.java** file, I guess, and I should add it after **cordova build android** has successfully run. I'll try it - in a couple of days I'll need it :)

Comment: I need my current view should go back on pressing my hardware back button on android phone. This works if i click on back button of page in framework7